# My son isn't smiling back at us anymore when we pick him up from infant care

Tags: infant, daycare

We began to send our 3month (almost 4 month) old son to infant care. The first two days are half-days only. On the second day, after we picked him up from the center, he didn't smile back at us as usual. Is it because he has never separated with us before? Is that normal?

At home he stays only with us. We are staying overseas, so there are no in-laws or other family who can look after him. And as our house is pretty tiny, we don't have visitors. We usually go out with him during weekends. And sometimes meet other people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Babies that age don't accurately display their emotions. Just because he smiles one day and not another day doesn't mean he was happier or less happy. One good way to know if your baby had a good day is by inquiring with the caregivers. Did he eat well? Sleep well? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back off of what was already said, kids don't really express emotions just yet, and at (I'm assuming) now 4 months, a baby is only just now beginning to become interactive.

The short story is: Don't sweat it. If that's the only thing that's different, then your child is fine. As was said before, focus on the logistics of a child transitioning to daycare: Amount they ate, amount of sleep, tummy time, etc. Its an adjustment and 1 day is not statistically significant in even the most remote way.

I'm overseas also. No family close by. Two working parents. Its a tough deal sometimes. Our son was the same way in the that he didn't really see anyone else for a while. Its not necessarily a bad or a good thing at that age.

Children also mirror us a whole lot at that age. Maybe you were tired that day and didn't smile as brightly as normal so your child didn't reflect it back. Maybe your child was tired that day because he/she didn't sleep as well in a new place. I would personally be concerned if your baby was regularly socially interactive (few weeks) and then it stopped abruptly and didn't return. But that's with my child. As I said before, each day, just like each kid, is different. And adjusting takes time.

Remember: You know your child best. If something is wrong: You will know.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. We already moved to a little bigger place, so we have to take him out of the center which is far from our new place and now sending him to a nanny. That nanny has total 4 kids, 3 babies(including our son) and one 2-year-old girl. She put the girl inside the cot with an iPad all day long. My wife's concern is having a 2-year-old kid near the babies. We will send him to the nanny for one month as trial and later we will decide. We will also check other day care centers near to our new place or our work.